# failed to connect to excel connection manager

Tags: excel, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

Good day guys, i have been struggling for days to connect to excel as a data source, i kept getting this error message while trying to select  sheet name. At first i found a solution that told me to install the 32bit ace oledb drive which i did and it worked, but then i tried running another project and it started to give  the same error message, i have tried almost every fix i have come across on the internet but still yet it keeps failing, i even uninstalled my ssdt to see if it would help but still same error message, i have changed run64bitruntime to false still not working. i need help guys, thanks.

"TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

---

Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager'.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpPlF.jpg)

Comment: are you trying to process an XLS or XLSX? You need different drivers for each. I actually use an add on from ZappySys to process Excel sheets. To me, Excel is a very bad source, but sometimes you have no choice.

Comment: i actually convert the XLSX to XLS to be able to use the 32bit driver but still it doesnt work, pls can you tell me more about the zappySys

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you describe more specific about your first workaround? (about that "32bit ace oledb drive"). I am really frustrating since i only start learning about SSIS and BI things but met this brick wall. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are converting it already, you should just convert it all the way to CSV. It will save a ton of headaches

Comment: Make sure that the specified file exists and is not in use.

Comment: @KeithL for the project's sake an excel source is recommended,the major reason why the file hasn't been converted to another format.@XuananNguyen you need to download Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 32bit drive, but it would recommend you to uninstall current 64bit if that's installed, this was my first fix but later on started failing, so i really dont know if its reliable.@WolfgangKais specified file exist and not in use but it still fails pls i would really appreciate if you knew any other work around this because its almost 4 days now i have been on this problem, thanks guys for all the replies.

Comment: I wasn't exactly clear why Excel files are bad sources. Here it is. 1. The files were most likely touched to be created. Most systems do not spit out Excel files therefore you have the human element which eventually will do something to cause problems (leading 0's of a string dropped for example). 2. The SSIS tools including ACE guess at data types which may not match what you want. You cannot pick them. the worse are when the first 10 records are null. It's always wrong. I highly recommend ZappySys (I have no affiliation other than a user). For $1200, you can at least choose data types.

Comment: FOUND A SOLUTION:

I changed the entire project to 32-bit.
In the excel source, i used explicit sql statement instead of views or sheet name.
RECOMMENDATION:

Always test sql statement querying excel in SSMS:

SELECT *
 FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0',
   'Excel 12.0 Xml;
    Database=C:\project msbi\OLTP\shaddy outlaw.xlsx',
    'SELECT * FROM [Sales$A1:D2]');

 SELECT *
 FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0',
   'Excel 12.0 Xml;
    Database=C:\project msbi\OLTP\shaddy outlaw.xlsx',
    'SELECT * FROM [Sales$]');